# `const_missing': uninitialized constant (NameError) - Require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting `const_missing': uninitialized constant Disc::Foo1 (NameError) while executing the code

**disc.rb**

```
module Disc
  MAPPING = {
  :new => {
    :first => Foo1,
    :second => Foo2
  },
  :old => {
    :third => Foo3,
    :fourth => Foo4
  }

  def run
    # :new and :first is example but will be any value decided based on the logic dynamically.
    cls = MAPPING[:new][:first]
    cls.new.execute
  end
}
end
```

**foo1.rb**

```
class Foo1
  def initialize
  end

  def execute
    puts "f1"
  end
end
```

**foo2.rb**

```
class Foo2
  def initialize
  end

  def execute
    puts "f2"
  end
end
```

**foo3.rb**

```
class Foo3
  def initialize
  end

  def execute
    puts "f3"
  end
end
```

**foo4.rb**

```
class Foo4
  def initialize
  end

  def execute
    puts "f4"
  end
end
```

I am new to ruby. I tried to find the solution and found that I have to add require clause and tried many things but didn't work.
Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: You did not post how you are using the module `Disc1`. Did you do a `require 'foo1'` somewhere prior to running `run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby can't autoload files — you need to explicitly tell it to load them. Just by sitting in the same directory they will not do anything. This is because, unlike some other languages, there is no predictable set mapping between file names and their contents, so Ruby can't know where the class you wanted is. You have to

```
require './foo1'
require './foo2'
require './foo3'
require './foo4'
```

Alternately, you could do it a bit smarter:

```
%w(./foo1 ./foo2 ./foo3 ./foo4).each do |file|
  require file
end
```

---

Now that you know about `require`... Saying that Ruby can't autoload files was a lie to tell people new to Ruby. Ruby can totally autoload files. But you still have to tell it what they are and where to find them. Just by sitting in the same directory they will not do anything. You have to

```
autoload(:Foo1, './foo1.rb')
autoload(:Foo2, './foo2.rb')
autoload(:Foo3, './foo3.rb')
autoload(:Foo4, './foo4.rb')
```

The files will not be loaded, unless you try to access the named classes; when you do so, Ruby will remember you told it where to find those classes, and load the corresponding file. This saves the program start time and memory, as only the actually needed files will be loaded.

You can also do this instead:

```
# for each `./foo*.rb` file
Dir.glob('./foo*.rb').each do |file|
  # turn it into the class name; e.g. `./foo1.rb' -> :Foo1
  classname = file[%r{\./(.*)\.rb$}, 1].capitalize.to_sym
  # then tell Ruby that that classname can be found in that file
  autoload(classname, file)
end
```

However, since you explicitly have the classes in your `MAPPING`, autoloading will not help you — all of the foo files will be autoloaded at the moment `MAPPING` is defined, so there is no benefit to using `autoload` here. If you stored names instead of class objects themselves, and used `Object.const_get` to look up the class object constant, then it would work:

```
autoload(:Foo1, './foo1.rb')
# `./foo1.rb` is not yet loaded

MAPPING = {
  new: {
    first: :Foo1,
    # ...
  },
  # ...
}
# `./foo1.rb` is still not loaded:
# we haven't used the `Foo1` constant yet
# (we did use `:Foo1` symbol, but that is a completely different thing)

cls = Object.const_get(MAPPING[:new][:first])
# `./foo1.rb` is now loaded, and `cls` is `Foo1`
```

Comment: Thanks ! This solved the mentioned problem. Actually Foo1, Foo2... are child classes of Fo1, Fo2 etc and they are child classes of F1, F2... It is showing the same error for Fo1.. Does that mean I have to add require clause in parent classes also even if I have mentioned the inheritance like ```class Foo1 < Fo1```

Comment: As I said, Ruby does not know where a class is defined, you have to tell it to load each file it needs. If you have `class Foo1 < Fo1; end`, this will be an error unless Ruby was previously taught about `Fo1` (either through `require './here_is_fo1.rb'` or `autoload(:Fo1, './here_is_fo1.rb')`. If you don't do that, Ruby has no reason to suspect `Fo1` is defined in `./here_is_fo1.rb`, inheritance or no inheritance.

Comment: Got it. I think this is applicable to classes only, not modules.

Comment: Nothing here is specific to classes; every constant works this way. `module A`, `class B`, `C = 42`, all of them behave exactly the same way. If you are coming from e.g. Python, "module" is a very different thing in Ruby. `foo1.rb` is a file, not a module. `Disc` is a module, not a file. `Foo1` is a class, but also a module (since `Class` is a subclass of `Module`). (I am guilty of messing up the terminology; I fixed the answer.)